# Pytest - Writing to real database while test script runs in test client with @pytest.fixture

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, pytest, peewee

I have test client which is implemented using `@pytest.fixture` client. In test client I have all my database tables/modals. Inside the test script block, I want to be able to write log records to real database tables, not to test client tables. Test script works fine, however there is no change at the real database tables.

Here is the simplified example:

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    tables = [
        User,
        Profile
    ]
    with db.atomic():
        db.drop_tables(tables)
        db.create_tables(tables)

    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client
        with db.atomic():
            db.drop_tables(tables)
```

```
def test_script(client):
    with db.atomic():
        User.create(
            name = "example",
            surname = "example"
        )
    
    assert True == True
```

Additionally, I don't does it matter but I am using PeeWee as ORM and SQLite for storage.

Comment: How did you verify that the test scripts work fine?